# How to find a method in assembly code

Tags: c++, assembly

From a memory leak log I have the following info:

TestApp.exe! + 2238ch

Let us say this means that method at offset '2238c' (hex value) is leaking.

How can I locate the corresponding method in my source code? I have the linker map (testapp.map) but not sure how to use it.

This is a C++ application compiled in VS2008.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your map file will have a bunch of entries like these:

```
 0001:00000070       ??0logic_error@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z 00401070 f i scratch.obj
 0001:000000e0       _main                      004010e0 f   scratch.obj
 0001:00000310       ??1?$list@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@V?$allocator@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@@std@@@std@@QAE@XZ 00401310 f i scratch.obj
 0001:00000330       ??1?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@QAE@XZ 00401330 f i scratch.obj
 0001:00000360       ?_Buynode@?$list@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@V?$allocator@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@@std@@@std@@IAEPAU_Node@?$_List_nod@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@V?$allocator@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@@std@@@2@XZ 00401360 f i scratch.obj
 0001:00000380       ?clear@?$list@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@V?$allocator@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ 00401380 f i scratch.obj
 0001:000003f0       ?_Buynode@?$list@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@V?$allocator@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@@std@@@std@@IAEPAU_Node@?$_List_nod@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@V?$allocator@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@@std@@@2@PAU342@0ABV?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@@Z 004013f0 f i scratch.obj
 0001:00000480       ?_Incsize@?$list@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@V?$allocator@V?$variant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_NUvoid_@0detail@boost@@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@U3045@@boost@@@std@@@std@@IAEXI@Z 00401480 f i scratch.obj
```

This shows you exactly how your code is laid out in memory. e.g. main() starts at E0 and ends at 30F in segment 1.

You just need to go through the address list to see where the address you were given lands. One thing to look out for is there are usually multiple segments, but you can usually deduce which one has the code you're interested in.

Comment: one question for clarity sake: in the above I can see main() starts at 0001:000000e0 but how did you find it ends at 30F?

Comment: Thanks Ferruccio. In my log I have an address which is not listed in the map file. Say I have two methods listed at 3187c and 318bc but my log shows address 318a4h. Can I assume it is called inside the method at 3187c or is there something wrong?

Comment: @Sesh - yes, that's correct. The address will not be an exact match unless it crashes on the very first instruction of a method, which is extremely unlikely since it's probably just setting up the stack frame.

Comment: Great! thanks. I have already marked your post as the expected answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`objdump`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) -- that should tell you the function-address mapping.

From Ferruccio: The Windows version of that is dumpbin, it comes with Visual Studio

Comment: The Windows version of that is dumpbin, it comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: objdump -d --start-address=ADDRESS --stop-address=ADDRESS+δ

Answer (score 0):

Also you can generate assembly when building - take a look at the compiler settings, the option is IIRC /FAs.